# Group by day from timestamp

Tags: mysql, sql

In my `posts` table, it saves timestamp for each post record.

What query can group posts by day, using this timestamp column?

Answer (score 79, accepted):

How about this? Using the [`DATE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date) function:

```
 SELECT DATE(FROM_UNIXTIME(MyTimestamp)) AS ForDate,
        COUNT(*) AS NumPosts
 FROM   MyPostsTable
 GROUP BY DATE(FROM_UNIXTIME(MyTimestamp))
 ORDER BY ForDate
```

This will show you the number of posts on each date that the table has data for.

Comment: I found my answer, but your answer incorrect, it's return null, correct is : `DATE(FROM_UNIXTIME(timestamp))`

Comment: @p.campbell : how can limit rows for each date ? example : for `2011-05-11` i have 10 post and for `2011-05-12` 20 post, i want show `2 post` for each date, can you help me ?

Comment: How would you like to decide which 2 to show? First of the day, or last of the day, or most views, or other? Kindly suggest this is a whole new question altogether. If you post it, likely you'll get a great answer quickly!

Comment: @Dems : ok, i'm waiting for your answer .

Comment: @p.campbell: no, it is consist of this question, i want just show 2 of last posts in each date

Comment: For those wanting to know how to do this with multiple somethings: `SELECT user_id, DATE(FROM_UNIXTIME(timestamp)) AS date, COUNT(*) AS numPosts FROM posts GROUP BY user_id, DATE(FROM_UNIXTIME(timestamp)) ORDER BY date`. This would tell you how many posts each user had on each day.

Comment: A proper local time should be set right ? Otherwise totals will be in UTC and in most cases will not make sense, as UTC times may span to 2 different days in local time.

Answer (score 51):

```
SELECT DATE(timestamp) AS ForDate,
        COUNT(*) AS NumPosts
 FROM   user_messages
 GROUP BY DATE(timestamp)
 ORDER BY ForDate
```

This found for me. I have timestamp like "2013-03-27 15:46:08".

Comment: This worked for in MySQL 5.1.52. DATE(FROM_UNIXTIME(MyTimestamp)) in previous answer returned null.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
(
    SELECT DATE(FROM_UNIXTIME(MyTimestamp)) AS ForDate,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY DATE(FROM_UNIXTIME(MyTimestamp)) ORDER BY MyTimeStamp) AS PostRowID,
           *
    FROM   MyPostsTable
)
    AS sequenced_daily_posts
WHERE
    ForDate = <whatever date(s) you want>
    AND PostRowID <= 2
```

Comment: Thanks, but see my last comment : `i want just show 2 of last posts in each date` I think this query only show posts that on date of it has 2 post

Comment: I Tested You query and it return syntax error in `(PARTITION BY DATE(FROM_UNIXTIME(MyTimestamp)))`

Comment: If a day has 1 post, it will show one post for that day.  If a day has 2 posts, it will show both posts for that day.  If a day has 3 or more posts, it will only show the first 2 posts for that day.  (Add DESC to the ORDER BY to make it show the last two posts of each day.)  This limit of 2 per day has no bearing on whether you have a hundred days, totalling upto 200 returned records.

Comment: The syntax error is due to an extra ) in there that was deleted in an edit.  You must have copied before I noticed.

Comment: Oh, and apparently MySQL doesn't support the ROW_NUMBER() windowed function, so you can ignore this answer.  Sorry.

Comment: Ok, that's right, but when run this query : `SELECT * FROM(SELECT DATE(FROM_UNIXTIME(add_time)) AS ForDate,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY DATE(FROM_UNIXTIME(add_time)) ORDER BY add_time) AS PostRowID,* FROM snm_posts ) AS sequenced_daily_posts WHERE PostRowID <= 2` return this error : `You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(PARTITION BY DATE(FROM_UNIXTIME(add_time)) ORDER BY add_time) AS PostRowID,* FR' at line 1`

Comment: asked this question as new question, if have a idea, please post your answer on it : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5971434/mysql-limit-by-dupplicate-value-of-rows thanks

Answer (score 0):

I did a lot of research about this error and got a solution that if you are select timestamp within DATE then you have to use this symbol (``) before and after of column name.

```
select DATE(addedon) as addedon, count(*) from data where id= '$bid' GROUP BY DATE(addedon)
```