# Limit query results to two rows per group

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a query to list all posts:

```
SELECT *, DATE(FROM_UNIXTIME(`timestamp`)) `date` 
FROM `posts`
ORDER BY `date` DESC
```

The query list all rows, I want to only show last 2 post for each `date`, how can I do this?

Comment: Are you looking to group your results by date? Your question is not very clear - can you clarify? What does "show for example 2 post each date" mean?

Comment: no, with given query, if i have 10 post in 2011-05-11, all of them lists in result, but i want only 2 post shows on result

Comment: Which  two for each date do you want to show?

Comment: @soandos: for example last 2 posts on each date

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This might work, though I couldn't say much about it's performance...

```
SELECT DATE(FROM_UNIXTIME(MyTimestamp)) AS ForDate, *
FROM   MyPostsTable
WHERE  2 >=
(
    SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM   MyPostsTable AS lookup
    WHERE  DATE(FROM_UNIXTIME(lookup.MyTimestamp)) = DATE(FROM_UNIXTIME(MyPostsTable.MyTimestamp))
    AND    lookup.MyTimeStamp >= MyPostsTable.MyTimestamp
)
```

Comment: Thanks, i tested it, but again it return list of all rows :(

Comment: There was typo.  You'll probably find it was excluding one row from each day.  `2 <=` has been changed to `2 >=`

Answer (score 0):

I'm adapting a sql server/oracle solution to your world.  Other column would be the ID of the table and then you could use that in a correlated subquery to get the rest of the columns.  Let me know if it works for next time I use MySQL

```
select l.DATE(FROM_UNIXTIME(`timestamp`)), l.`otherColumn`, count(*) as num
from `posts` as l
left outer join fruits as r
    on l.DATE(FROM_UNIXTIME(`timestamp`)) = r.DATE(FROM_UNIXTIME(`timestamp`))        
       and l.`otherColumn` >= r.`otherColumn`
group by l.DATE(FROM_UNIXTIME(`timestamp`)), l.`otherColumn`
having count(*) <= 2
```

Comment: Seems the same logic as in my answer, but expressed differently, so it looks like it should work.  Wouldn't know which would perform better though, or if they even give the same execution plan.