# How do i limit rows per group?

Tags: mysql, group-by, greatest-n-per-group

I am using mysql. I don't care how many groups get returned back but if a single group has more then 4 items i only want the first 4. How do i write a statement that only returns 4rows per group? As a temporary fix i am just returning them all and filtering it out in code. Its still pretty fast although it would be easier if i knew syntax

Comment: What do you mean by a group ? You mean using GROUP BY ? Also it would help us to understand your question if you can post your current SQL Query.

Comment: How to select first 4 records, by datetime field? Show you table structure (CREATE TABLE) and desired result.

Comment: @danishgoel: `select * from MainTable where blah in @ls`. Makes you feel kind of silly. Maybe you meant code? Thats a large edit but i am sure its easier to understand reading the little i wrote rather then random code that is large and cryptic written in my own personal style

Comment: Do you want to LIMIT the rows before doing a GROUP BY ?

Comment: @Devart: I dont. I split the array into multiple arrays sharing the same fk_id then i take the first four items.

Comment: @Glide: No. I already limit the `@ls` array so the results wont be too big. I just get more then i need

Comment: did you look at this: http://blog.aharbick.com/2006/09/mysql-groupwise-limiting.html is this related to your question?

Comment: You may want to read this article: [Within-group quotas (Top N per group)](http://www.artfulsoftware.com/infotree/queries.php#104).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Limit query results to two rows per group](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5971434/limit-query-results-to-two-rows-per-group)

Comment: If you want to find first 4 records in the group, you should sort result. Right? What is the criteria?

Comment: I think 'eugene y' gave you good link.

Comment: You should put an example into your question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, I believe the following answer should do approximately what you need (note: I've included two test tables and their associated inserts as an example since your table structure was not provided):

Given these tables and data:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS tCustomer;
CREATE TABLE tCustomer (
     customerId INT(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL auto_increment,
     name       VARCHAR(8),
     PRIMARY KEY (customerId)
) AUTO_INCREMENT=1;

INSERT INTO tCustomer VALUES
(NULL, 'Alex'),
(NULL, 'Bob'),
(NULL, 'Carl')
;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS tPurchases;
CREATE TABLE tPurchases (
    purchaseId   INT(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL auto_increment,
    customerId   INT(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    amount       DECIMAL(9,2),
    purchaseDate DATETIME,
    PRIMARY KEY (purchaseId),
    CONSTRAINT fk_customer FOREIGN KEY (customerId) REFERENCES tCustomer (customerId)
) AUTO_INCREMENT=1;

INSERT INTO tPurchases VALUES
(NULL, 1, 1.00, '2011-01-01 08:00'),
(NULL, 1, 1.01, '2011-01-02 08:00'),
(NULL, 1, 1.02, '2011-01-03 08:00'),
(NULL, 1, 1.03, '2011-01-04 08:00'),
(NULL, 1, 1.04, '2011-01-05 08:00'),
(NULL, 1, 1.05, '2011-01-06 08:00'),
(NULL, 2, 1.01, '2011-01-01 08:00'),
(NULL, 2, 1.02, '2011-01-02 08:00'),
(NULL, 3, 1.01, '2011-01-02 08:00'),
(NULL, 3, 1.02, '2011-01-04 08:00'),
(NULL, 3, 1.03, '2011-01-08 08:00')
;
```

The following SQL will select purchase data by customer returning no more than the 4 most recent purchases:

```
SELECT
    tC.customerId, tC.name, tP.purchaseDate, tP.amount, COUNT(tPNewer.customerId) newerCt
FROM
                    tCustomer  tC
    INNER JOIN      tPurchases tP      ON tC.customerId = tP.customerId
    LEFT OUTER JOIN tPurchases tPNewer ON tP.customerId = tPNewer.customerId AND tPNewer.purchaseId > tP.purchaseId
GROUP BY
    tC.customerId,
    tC.name,
     tP.purchaseDate,
     tP.amount
HAVING
    newerCt < 4 -- Ignore rows that have more than 3 newer records
ORDER BY
     tC.customerId,
     tP.purchaseDate desc
;
```

Here is the resulting output from this select (note that Alex's oldest transactions are absent):

```
+------------+------+---------------------+--------+---------+
| customerId | name | purchaseDate        | amount | newerCt |
+------------+------+---------------------+--------+---------+
|          1 | Alex | 2011-01-06 08:00:00 |   1.05 |       0 |
|          1 | Alex | 2011-01-05 08:00:00 |   1.04 |       1 |
|          1 | Alex | 2011-01-04 08:00:00 |   1.03 |       2 |
|          1 | Alex | 2011-01-03 08:00:00 |   1.02 |       3 |
|          2 | Bob  | 2011-01-02 08:00:00 |   1.02 |       0 |
|          2 | Bob  | 2011-01-01 08:00:00 |   1.01 |       1 |
|          3 | Carl | 2011-01-08 08:00:00 |   1.03 |       0 |
|          3 | Carl | 2011-01-04 08:00:00 |   1.02 |       1 |
|          3 | Carl | 2011-01-02 08:00:00 |   1.01 |       2 |
+------------+------+---------------------+--------+---------+
```