# Remove hours, minutes and seconds from crdate in TCA typo3

Tags: typo3

i have configuration in news tca like:

```
'ctrl' => [
    'tstamp' => 'tstamp',
    'crdate' => 'crdate',
```

with this, news will be saved like `1535967103` in database, with hours, minutes and seconds. I want trim this information and have it like `1535932800`

How can i get this in TCA configuration?

Comment: crdate is an internal TYPO3 field. Why do you want this altered? Perhaps you're trying to do something that can be done differently.

Comment: i want to sort elements by day and i think about changes in crdate as nice field, but maybe if it can cause problems with typo3, i can use another, new field for this purpose.

Comment: You can use MySQL date functions for that (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5970938/group-by-day-from-timestamp), though that might not work with Doctrine (not sure), which is used since TYPO3 8.1. If that doesn't work I would use a separate field for that.

Comment: thanks for answer, i know method with mysql (its work well for BE but i have big problem with FE, not possible to use ATM). I know solution with processDatamap_afterDatabaseOperations but i looking for something as clean as possible (ideal is done in tca, any secret method, trick?) but if i didn't found something clean i use separate field as you recommend :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, i created new field with datetime, its take the same value as crdate.

then i created `processDatamap_preProcessFieldArray(&$fieldArray, $table)` where i do:

`$dateTime = (new \DateTime())->setTimestamp($fieldArray['datetime']);
 $dateTime->setTime(00, 00, 00);
 $fieldArray['datetime'] = $dateTime->getTimestamp();`

in `ext_localconf` i added:

`$GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['SC_OPTIONS']['t3lib/class.t3lib_tcemain.php']['processDatamapClass']['si_news'] =
    \Sozialinfo\SiNews\Hooks\TCEmainHook::class;
$GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['SC_OPTIONS']['t3lib/class.t3lib_tcemain.php']['processCmdmapClass']['si_news'] =
    \Sozialinfo\SiNews\Hooks\TCEmainHook::class;`

and now i have crdate without hours, minutes and seconds(in new field, crdate untouched) and i can do sorting with this field.

The only solution for remove seconds from crdate which i found is to use `processDatamap_afterDatabaseOperations` and use custom query with `$GLOBALS['TYPO3_DB']`. Its little dirty IMO.

I use new field instead overwrite crdate because as someone said: crdate is an internal TYPO3 field. So i didn't change internal TYPO3 field.

Thanks all for help.

Answer (score 1):

You can always sort by day, even with timestamps having seconds. The rest of the sorting criteria for identical timestamps usually will be the autoincrement field, so the result of ascending or descending sorting by timestamp will be the same.

Unless you want to group by a certain day, having another timestamp would not make any difference.

Anything else can be done in the frontend output, so you can skip the seconds while formatting the timestamp via date or strftime.

Comment: i have the same feeling like you about sorting in be. But done sorting in frontend with not crdate with seconds is very hard for me because i have only repository function and i can't use mysql like in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5970938/group-by-day-from-timestamp

Repo: `public function createOrderingsFromDemand(\GeorgRinger\News\Domain\Model\DemandInterface $demand)
    {
        return [
            'crdate' => QueryInterface::ORDER_DESCENDING,
            'istopnews' => QueryInterface::ORDER_DESCENDING,
            'sorting' => QueryInterface::ORDER_ASCENDING`

Comment: So you actually want to query by day and sort within that day by istopnews and sorting. This is the missing information in the original question.

Comment: important for me in this question is only sorting by year, month, day from crdate. i exactly know how to do sorting by topNew and sorting.

Comment: So it would not help that much to reduce the timestamp in crdate to days and cut hours, minutes and seconds, since you would still be missing month and year.

Comment: i added answer which show all possible solution which i found, thanks for help :)

Answer (score 0):

tstamp and crdate can not be rounded. They're always per second.

Comment: it can be done  for crdate with hooks, but i looking for more clean way. Maybe if i need date without seconds, should i use another field? Its is possible to round field value in tca in "clean" way?

Comment: It's probably not a very good idea to change the storage of these mostly internally handled TYPO3 fields artificially. I'm unsure on the impact to the core if you do that and can't tell you out of the box which areas rely on a per-second storage for these fields and what could possibly go wrong.