# GroupBy can't be translated

Tags: c#, .net-core, group-by, entity-framework-core, linq-to-entities

I'm trying to remove duplicates from my database. I'm using Entity Framework Core and .NET 5. EF Core is having trouble materializing my group by:

```
protected async Task RemoveDuplicates(CryptoInfoContext cryptoContext)
{
    try
    {
        var duplicates = cryptoContext.HistoricalCandles
            .GroupBy(x => new { x.StartDate, x.GranularitySeconds })
            .Where(x => x.Count() > 1)
            .ToList()
            .Select(x => x.FirstOrDefault())
            .ToList();

        cryptoContext.RemoveRange(duplicates);
        await cryptoContext.SaveChangesAsync();
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex);
    }
}
```

I'm getting an error:

> Unable to translate the given 'GroupBy' pattern. Call 'AsEnumerable' before 'GroupBy' to evaluate it client-side

I don't feel like materializing all of my rows to remove the duplicates.
Is there a list of known issues with group by?
how can I work around this issue?

Comment: Please look for other questions on this error. It's posted multiple times a week.

Comment: Thanks, I see now.  I'll post an answer soon

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks to @GertArnold for pointing me in the right direction.   Apparently EF Group by only support aggregate queries.

As pointed out by this [article](https://blog.jetbrains.com/dotnet/2020/11/25/getting-started-with-entity-framework-core-5/):

```
var ctx = new EntertainmentDbContext(conString);

var dataTask = ctx
            .Ratings
            .GroupBy(x => x.Source)
            .Select(x => new {Source = x.Key, Count = x.Count()})
            .OrderByDescending(x => x.Count)
            .ToListAsync();

var data = await dataTask;
```

Which will generate SQL like so:

```
SELECT "r"."Source", COUNT(*) AS "Count"
FROM "Ratings" AS "r"
GROUP BY "r"."Source"
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
```

**Note:** currently pretty much nothing else works, you CANNOT even apply a where before the group by.

Additionally there is an open [EF Core issue](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/17068)  Please vote on it so they actually fix this instead of pushing it another release

Comment: I never had issues using `Where` with `GroupBy`. The problem is the query, not EF Core. In fact, I wouldn't even use EF Core for such a query because it can't use ranking functions like `ROW_NUMBER` which make selecting the "latest" record by date a *lot* easier, avoiding multiple scans and sorts. ORMs aren't built for reporting queries, they're built to load object graphs. LINQ makes things easier, but if you have even a moderate amount of data or complexity, it's better to create a reporting view (at least) and map *those* results to objects

Comment: If writing the SQL query is easier and runs faster than the equivalent LINQ query, use the SQL query.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, your right I probably can just end up using raw SQL from EF and leverage its model binding (Mostly because I'm lazy, and I need to push something out quick, instead of using dapper).  I'll update the answer when I get back to the project

Answer (score 0):

Your group by value is I guess a DateTime. Only scalar values can be used in group by clause, because SQL cannot group by on date either.
Look also [this git issue on more detailed explanation](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/17068) and [this question on SQL details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5970938/group-by-day-from-timestamp).

As for a workaround - I did't try it, but probably you could group by time string representation or ticks.

Comment: Wrong. EF core 5 doesn't support GroupBy with anything but an aggregation clause, that's all. Of course SQL can group by DateTime.